# Projecting rectangle on Sphere in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a VR project I have a 360 panorama on a sphere in which users need to mark something by "drawing" a rectangle with their head movement. So let's say you'd want to mark the person in the image below you start drawing at for example the top left corner [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUaID.jpg).
Then move your head to the bottom right and end up with a rectangle, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1uj2.jpg).

How would i go about doing this? I guess i would somehow have to project a plane on the panorama sphere based on the camera position? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you can achieve this using the Projector, it requires 2 of the shaders that come with the Unity Standard Assets Package.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-32351

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to determine the gesture/action for starting to draw and an indicator for each corner of the rect. (you are basically creating a mesh/quad at runtime, herewith is a tutorial to help you with that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmuHI_wsOgI )
2. Now you need to find the wanted vertex positions for the quad. I would try to raycast and get the hit.point values. collect 4 raycast points and assign their values to the mesh vertices.